# If rows (columns) of matrix $A$ are linearly dependent then $A \sim \begin{pmatrix} E_r&0\\ 0&0 \end{pmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that if rows (columns) of matrix $A$ are linearly dependent then, using elementary transformations of type $II$ with rows and columns, matrix $A$ can be reduced to the form $$\begin{pmatrix} E_r&0\\ 0&0 \end{pmatrix},$$
where $E_r$ - identity matrix of rank $r$

I know that this way of matrix transformation is similar to Gaussian Method. Furthermore, for specific matrix I am able to perform this transformation. But it is unclear to me how to describe it in general case (except for enumerating all typical cases).